# Xcode 6.0.1 - some linked folder images not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting images that previously worked coming back as nil in the latest version of Xcode, nothing has changed but the image objects are coming back as null.  I've tried cleaning and deleting the app, and even copied the entire folder to see if that was the issue, the folder shows up in the build phases "copy bundle resources".  The folder and file names are correct, this project has been compiled and launched half a dozen times.  The @2x file is also in the folder.

```
UIImage *iSearch = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/assets/images/controls/search_bg.png"];
UIImage *iSearchB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/assets/images/controlsb/search_bg.png"];
NSLog(@"iSearch: %@, iSearchB: %@", iSearch, iSearchB);
```

Log:
2014-09-23 14:29:45.651 SmartChoice[16178:469424] iSearch: (null), iSearchB: (null)

I also have another issue where this is failing on
AppDelegate.h

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([IWAppDelegate class]));
```

Instead of the actual code on the view controller in the call stack.

//update, solved the second issue using info here, unsure why they turned that off by default: http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/

Comment: But it is nutty to have an image with slashes in its name! Does the image _really_ have those slashes, or are you assuming that this will magically be the same as looking in your bundle hierarchy? It's not; this should _never_ have worked.

Comment: If you use a folder reference, you don't bring the files into the project directly and anything in the folder gets pulled in, you have to use the folder hierarchy in the name, not just the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using `imageNamed:` with a fake name with slashes to dive into a folder hierarchy. That's fragile and unsupported, and the fact that it ever worked is just chance. Don't gamble. Either use an asset catalog (far and away the best approach nowadays) or use one of the NSBundle methods that lets you specify the subdirectory, such as `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, apparently the preceding slash, which was required before, does not work.  I have changed it to [UIImage imageNamed:@"assets/images/controls/search_bg.png"]; and it works.